# How to slice weather data from a dictionary and re-write?

Tags: python-3.x, list, datetime, dictionary

I got this bit of data from the weatherbit-api. And I really need help in slicing the data.

The follwing is my code:

```
from weatherbit.api import Api
api_key = "******************"
api = Api(api_key)

Location = "Tokyo"
Day_of_Forecast = '3'
forecast = api.get_forecast(days = Day_of_Forecast, city= Location)
forecast_list = forecast.get_series(['temp', 'max_temp', 'min_temp', 'weather'])
print(forecast_list)
```

And it returned like this:

```
[{'temp': 33, 'max_temp': 36.5, 'min_temp': 29.5, 'weather': {'icon': 'c03d', 'code': 803, 'description': 'Broken clouds'}, 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 7, 0, 0)},
{'temp': 31.3, 'max_temp': 35.3, 'min_temp': 28.8, 'weather': {'icon': 'c04d', 'code': 804, 'description': 'Overcast clouds'}, 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 8, 0, 0)},
{'temp': 30.7, 'max_temp': 34.4, 'min_temp': 28.4, 'weather': {'icon': 'c03d', 'code': 803, 'description': 'Broken clouds'}, 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 9, 0, 0)}]
```

So with the list above, How can I slice through it and re-write it to returned the result like this for example:

```
The weather forecast for Tokyo is:
On 7th of August 2019, the weather forecast is Broken clouds. The temperature will be 33 celsius degree, the maximum temperature will be 36.5 celsius degree and minimum temperature will be 29.5 degree.
On 8th of August , the weather forecast is Overcast clouds. The temperature will be 31.3 celsius degree, the maximum temperature will be 35.3 celsius degree and minimum temperature will be 28.8 degree.
On 9th of August , the weather forecast is Broken clouds. The temperature will be 30.7 celsius degree, the maximum temperature will be 34.4 celsius degree and minimum temperature will be 28.4 degree.
```

Sorry for this noob question but it is a part of my practice and I have been struggle with this for days. 
I am very appreciate for your help. Thank you so much.
Feel free to copy the list or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def better_forecast_list(forecast_list):
    better_list = []
    for forecast in forecast_list:
        better_list.append(
            f'''Today is {forecast['datetime']: %d %B %Y} \
             weather is {forecast['weather']['description']} \
             temp will be {forecast['temp']} 
            ''')
    return better_list
```

I've used `f` strings by the way. It's only available from python 3.7 up

Comment: Omg!! thank you so much. Based on your function, I sliced the list and re-write it successfully. Thank you so much man.!!!!